# How to call OnChangedProperty from a View for all Properties in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have in my Page1.xaml.cs (code-behind) an event which needs to change all properties in my ViewModel.

Here is an example: (Page1.xaml.cs)

```
public Page1()
{        
    InitializeComponent();

    example.Event += example_Event;
}

private void example_Event(...)
{ 
    // here I want to change all Properties in my ViewModel
}
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have a WebBrowser-Control that displays a .ppt. I want to update all of my Properties in my ViewModel when this Event gets triggered:

xaml.cs:

```
private void powerPointBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        oPPApplication.SlideShowNextSlide += ppApp_SlideShowNextSlide; //Event that gets triggered when i change the Slide in my WebBrowser-Control

    }

private void ppApp_SlideShowNextSlide(PPt.SlideShowWindow Wn)
    {
          // here i dont know how to get access to my Properties in my VM (i want to call OnChangedProperty(//for all properties in my VM))
    }
```

Comment: Fire the view model's PropertyChanged event with a null or empty property name.

Comment: yea, i know that i have to do it with string.empty ^^ but i dont know how to fire OnPropertyChanged in my Code-Behind to get the Properties in my VM.

Comment: We also don't know that, as you haven't shown us the relevant parts of your view model. I'd say, add a public method to the view model that calls OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: How about just raising datacontextchanged? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What do you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: I dont know how to explain any better... I edited my question (now with a real example). To simplify my question: I just want to update all of my  Properties in my VM from my Code-Behind (xaml.cs) when an event gets triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, View (including code behind) does not have responsibility to notify the ViewModel's properties to be updated, it should be the other way around. But, I see that in your case, you would like to do certain thing (in this case, retrieve the latest value of each properties) when handling some event, so here you are: some solutions for what you need.

In your VM, define a method that fires PropertyChanged to all properties:

```
public void UpdateAllProperties()
{
    // Call OnPropertyChanged to all of your properties
    OnPropertyChanged(); // etc. 
}
```

Then in your View's code behind, what you need is just calling that method:

```
// every View has a ViewModel that is bound to be View's DataContext. So cast it, and call the public method we defined earlier.
((MyViewModel)DataContext).UpdateAllProperties();
```

This approach is unfortunately not very elegant for MVVM style. I would suggest that you make this method/ event handler as a Bindable `ICommand`. So you don't need to write any code behind, for ex: In your VM define the `ICommand`.

```
public ICommand UpdateAllPropertiesCommand {get; private set;}
   = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand(UpdateAllProperties);
// You can switch the UpdateAllProperties method to private instead.
// Then remove any code behinds you had.
```

Then, in your View (xaml), you could bind the `ICommand` to certain control's event trigger.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<!--In one of the controls-->
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateAllPropertiesCommand , Mode=OneTime}"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Here, the command will be automatically called when handling the loaded event.